# vb.net sql select statement to find all Not Null's, do I need to use parameters?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameter-passing

I'm simply trying to find all records in my SQL database table that don't equal null. So when I wrote the select statement, I treat it like I would anything else to avoid sql injection issues.

Here's an example:

```vb
Command = New SqlCommand
connection.Open()
Command.Connection = connection
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [Comments] IS NOT NULL" 'Have tried [Comments]=@Comments
'Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", "IS NOT NULL")
da = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
da.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
For Each roww As DataRow In ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows
    If (Not IsDBNull(roww("Comments"))) Then
        IDLIST.Add(roww("TempID"))
        Comments_RichText.AppendText("Date of Service: " & roww("FromDate") & " | " & roww("Name") & vbNewLine & roww("Comments") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    End If
Next
connection.close
```

As you can see, I have tried both using a parameter to avoid SQL injection (but returns nothing) and no parameter which returns the correct rows. Why doesn't the parameter way work? Since I'm not concatenating anything in the statement such as a TextBox.Text or string, do I have to use a parameter for `IS NOT NULL`? Any help would be great because I don't understand why 1 way works and the other doesn't.

Comment: No, your query doesn't contain concatenated text from user inputs. There is no sql injection possible here and there is no need for parameters because your query is a constant string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterisation will not work, as this is going to use an equality operator to check, which doesn't work with literals like `IS NOT NULL`. It doesn't work how you think (it doesn't just rewrite the string with your parameters).

This is still pretty easy to achieve, though, using null coalescence like:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ISNULL([Comments].'Empty') != @Comments
```

With `@Comments` being 'Empty' when you wanted to find the empty ones, if you get what I mean. You could obviously use whatever string variable you wanted in place of `'Empty'`.